# Load and render layout

Tags: layout

I have code like below

```
class Digitech_Brandlogo_Adminhtml_BrandlogoController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    public function indexAction()
    {                          
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();         
    }
}
```

I would like to know what will do

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

Actually I would like to know execution flow.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`loadLayout()` loads the layout XML for the layout handles `<default>` and `<admin_brandLogo_index>` (the route name for this controller action). These handles can be defined in any XML files in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout` (i.e. in the theme, or its parent theme). From this merged XML it generates a hierarchy of blocks. It executes everything defined in these XML files: instantiates block objects, arranges them, calls actions on them.

`renderLayout()` calls the render method of the root block. Usually that's `toHtml()` and the page block with a template like `1column.phtml`, but it could be anything that is defined in the XML. This root block subsequently renders its children, if `getChildHtml()` is called from the template. The result is the complete HTML that will be sent as response.